# Acknowledging a coauthor for a particular result

Tags: mathematics, authorship, acknowledgement

I am writing a (math) paper that uses a result from an older paper that I coauthored with X. I proved some of the other things in the paper, but this particular result was proved entirely by X after I sent them an email asking about it, which ultimately led to the collaboration with X.

In my new paper I would like to somehow show my appreciation for X's contribution, without saying "They did it, not me" (I suppose this would be taboo). What would be a good way of expressing this in the Acknowledgements section?

Comment: Presumably you already cite your coauthored paper with X? Is there a reason to do more than that?

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it is simpler than that. You can, as I once did in an AMS journal, mark a proof or the statement of the theorem as "Proof by X".

Normally the Ack section is for acknowledging those who aren't authors.  So, if you mean that X isn't a coauthor on *this* paper you can add, there, your thanks for past collaborations that influenced this one especially for developing the proof of Theorem A.

Answer (score 2):

This other person already receives acknowledgement for their work through the fact that you will cite the joint paper you did together where the proof is located.  If you would like to do more than that (which sounds quite reasonable to me) then you can specifically note in your new paper that X proved the theorem on their own.  There is nothing taboo about this at all, since it is a standard aspect of research that co-authors may contribute different aspects of a paper.

As far as how to set this out in your new paper, you don't need to agonise over this.  Just make it a short parenthetic remark when you discuss the relevant theorem --- here is an example:

> Here we will make use of Theorem 4 in Dmath and X (2015) (actually proved entirely by X).  This theorem shows that...